# Redirect Self-Hosted Building Agent to Azure Devops Service

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following problem to solve but I cannot find the right documentation.
I just upgrade the version control software from TFS (on premise) to Azure Devops Service.
I have my own self-hosted building agents that are hooked upo with the TFS istance.
What I want to do now is to redirect them from pointing to TFS to pointing into Azure Devops Service.
I can find everything about the authentication part, token and so on but I miss the basic steps on reconfiguring the building agents themselves. Can someone help me by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reconfigure your build agents into Azure DevOps. [Remove and re-configure an agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#remove-and-re-configure-an-agent)

> To remove the agent:
>
> .\config remove
>
> After you've removed the agent, you can [configure it again](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#download-configure).

Comment: that's great, thank you very much! If I may ask, is there an easy to find where the agent directory is? So far I could find it only by diving into the search

Comment: Unfortunately TFS does not store the build agent path. However you can try to create a custom capability and save the path manually. [Capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#capabilities)